# Cant find element by xpath in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

There is a button that I want to click and it can be seen in the HTML source.

it's located on the dialog box named 'bonus al' here. [Related Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0lPM.jpg)

This is code that I tried to click with.

`get_bonus = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="linkLoginBonus"]'))).click()`

```html
<input type="button" class="awesome-button big" value="Bonus al" id="linkLoginBonus" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

I get this error:

```
python
'get_bonus= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="linkLoginBonus"]')))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:'
```

Comment: Could you provide the url of the webpage? Your XPath is correct. Most probably, the button you are looking for doesn't become clickable until you perform some action.

Comment: This is the link  but you should be logged in to reach that dialogbox  https://s1-tr.gladiatus.gameforge.com/game/index.php?mod=auction&sh=a2e5c0ef4a4ae7669953d93eba55fef9

Comment: Unfortunately, login is required.

Comment: What error is thrown when you use `driver.find_element_by_id("linkLoginBonus").click()`

Comment: I will try this:`driver.find_element_by_id("linkLoginBonus").click()` but it pops up in certain time period when it comes I'll try it . Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @HalilÇakır :  Can we have error stack trace for `driver.find_element_by_id("linkLoginBonus").click()` ? also use @ to reply

Comment: @cruisepandey Now I got this error :  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="linkLoginBonus"]"}

Comment: Can you share any dummy credentials if you've any  ?

Comment: There is no iframe or things about the alert to use switch method right?

Comment: @cruisepandey I created and will share with you soon.